# Complete Excel line export to other sheet when changing status

Tags: excel

I am an Excel beginner.

I would like to create an history depending on the status of the line ("Open" or "Closed") in the column A. When the status would pass from Open to Closed in column A, the all line would be exported to another sheet (Sheet 2 for example) which would be the history. I didn't manage to find a formula for this simple task. Neither know how to insert the matrix so that exported line goes under the last exported line...

Is this possible without using Access?

PLEASE HELP ME :)

Comment: How many other columns are you using??

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your data is in **Sheet1** and the history will be in **Sheet2**

Insert the following event macro in the **Sheet1** code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, N As Long, r As Range, Intr As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Intr = Intersect(Target, A)
    If Intr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In Intr
        If r.Value = "Closed" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                N = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                r.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(N, 1)
                r.EntireRow.Delete
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**